# Strange position in a inline-block div without canvas (see the example)

Tags: css, html

See http://log85.no-ip.org/q100.html

Why the second block is in that position? //in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed to add this CSS :

```
canvas{display:block;width:100px;height:100px;}
```

Update: It only because the canvas have a default size bigger than expected in this case witch cause a weird but "normal" reaction of the HTML.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Has something to do with the default width and heights of canvas.  If you set them to 100%, it fixes the issue.

Comment: Fixed but... I don't understand why. Is a gecko/webkit bug? Is the example code right? :S

Comment: It seems to have something to do with display:inline-block.  Because I can't produce the same results with float:left.  It may very well be a bug

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code, it somewhat fixes issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>[ LoG85 ] - [ Duda CSS ]</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {background:#012;text-align:center}
         .container {width:800px;margin:auto;border:1px solid blue}
         .block {display:inline-block;border:1px solid green;width:320px;height:240px}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">

         <div class="block"></div>        I removed <canvas></canvas> from here.
         <div class="block"></div>
         <div class="block"><canvas></canvas></div>
         <div class="block"><canvas></canvas></div>
         <div class="block"><canvas></canvas></div>
         <div class="block"><canvas></canvas></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Note : I haven't tested it on Chrome, since I don't have Chrome installed but it works fine in IE and Firefox.